# nagios change check command based on time period

Tags: nagios

I have a service that I'd like to change the check command for during different time periods.
I see that you can change the check_command live using external commands, but I would like to be able to configure this to happen in the object definition.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a custom script that takes a time period specification and two check commands and runs the appropriate command.  You might have to implement the time period checks yourself, but it shouldn't be too difficult.

You could also write two separate service checks with non-overlapping notification times (so that you either get alerts from one or the other but not both).

Comment: Can you do that for the same service (that is, same service_name)?

Comment: I suspect that you would need two service definitions for that option.

Comment: Seems to be the only way to do this.